# Can't assign value from table before cursor declaration in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I am not able to assign value to local variable from select statements. Please help me on this.

I want to assign value to local variable before cursor declaration. i want to use that local variable value in the cursor select statement.

have tried below code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC(IN STARTKEY BIGINT, IN ENDKEY BIGINT)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_var1 VARCHAR(100);
SELECT status into v_var1 from emp where emp_id=1000; -- this will return only one value
DECLARE C_CURSOR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT emp_code from company where status=v_var1;
OPEN C_CURSOR;
    FETCH PV INTO C_CURSOR;
    --
    --
    -- My logic 
CLOSE C_CURSOR;
END
@
```

Comment: fetch cursor into ...

Comment: Why not just put that first clause into your select? `SELECT emp_code from company join emp on emp.status=company.status where emp_id=1000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using nested BEGIN/END blocks to assign the value to the variable before using it in the cursor. (This works in other RBDMS).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC(IN STARTKEY BIGINT, IN ENDKEY BIGINT)
BEGIN -- Parent block
 DECLARE v_var1 VARCHAR(100);

 BEGIN -- Child block 1
  SELECT status into v_var1 from emp where emp_id=1000;
 END;

 BEGIN -- Child block 2
  DECLARE C_CURSOR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT emp_code FROM company WHERE status = v_var1;
  OPEN C_CURSOR;
    FETCH PV INTO C_CURSOR;
    -- Your logic ...
  CLOSE C_CURSOR;
 END;

END
@
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC(IN STARTKEY BIGINT, IN ENDKEY BIGINT)
language sql
specific testproc
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_var1 VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE v_sql VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE v_emp_code bigint;
    DECLARE C_CURSOR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR s1;
    SELECT status into v_var1 from emp where emp_id=1000; -- this will return only one value
    set v_sql ='SELECT emp_code from company where status = '''||v_var1||'''' ;

    PREPARE s1 from v_sql;
    OPEN C_CURSOR;
    FETCH C_CURSOR into v_emp_code;
    --
    --
    -- My logic 
    CLOSE C_CURSOR;
END
@
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your query like this

```
SELECT f1.emp_code from company f1 
inner join emp f2 on f1.status=f2.status and f2.emp_id=1000;
```